# How does mat-cell bind source given to mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to understand how `mat-cell` using `matCellDef` gets access to 
member of  `mat-table [dataSource]`

I know i can give `*ngIf` statements like `let user` and then use `user`, i just don't understand how user is initialized with an element from `dataSource` provided to `mat-table`

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

</table>
```